# Assigning AngularJS variable to name tag of html

Tags: html, angularjs

**Values**

`{{item.name1}}` is `item_name_1`

`{{item.description}}` is `Band`

**Case 1**

```
<input name="item_name_1" value={{item.description}}>
```

the text field contains `Band`

**Case 2**

```
<input  name={{item.name1}} value={{item.description}}>
```

the text field does not contain anything.

Any solutions for case 2?

Complete Code

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <form style="float:right" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@dialswap.com">
          <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">


          <!--Code to be Seen below --> 
          <div ng-repeat="items in item" >
               <input type="hidden" name="{{items.name}}" value={{item.description}}>
               <input type="hidden" name="{{items.amount}}" value=60>
          </div>


          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
          <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
          <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
          <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
          <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
          <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">  
        </form>

</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
$scope.item[0] = {
    name: 'item_name_1',
    amount:'amount_1',
    description: 'bands'
}
$scope.item[1] = {
    name: 'item_name_2',
    amount:'amount_2',
    description: 'bands'
}
});
```

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wedE5/2/

This works perfectly with one item and without ng-repeat.

Comment: will be better if you make some jsfiddle, have try add quote on the attirbute?

Comment: you should have double quotes around the values. The expressions will still evaluate normally.

Comment: quotes did not work . @Nick

Comment: please make jsfiddle, bcoz it work on my local.

Comment: can we see the controller you are working with? [here is a fiddle of what I think you are trying to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/wedE5/)

Comment: JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M2vBU/1/ this is for paypal checkout

Comment: nick i just edited your fiddle.  the code works perfectly fine if there is just one item. when there are more than one item, paypal requires you to give the name as item_name_1,item_name_2 so on and amount as amount_1 , amount_2 so on. It does not work if it is that way http://jsfiddle.net/wedE5/2/

Comment: This fiddle works with multiple items in your array. 
http://jsfiddle.net/WxRfW/

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo sorry the fiddle is not working :/

Comment: in what way is this not working...changed hidden inputs to text. here is the working fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/U79Uc/](http://jsfiddle.net/U79Uc/)

Comment: Also valid HTML is important. Input tags are always self-closing.

Comment: nick it works. sorry my bad. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-attr-name="item.name"` and `ng-attr-value="item.value"`